# Is it possible to achieve this in lightning data table in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience

[image]

Here in this image, let's take example of account and contact.
Account name will be in first column ie; Course name.
Then Patient Column onwards it will be depends on the how many contacts are belongs to that particular account. Suppose if two contacts then it will show one contact information in one line and other in second line in a same row.
If it's possible with lightning data table how??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by building custom Data Table and using rowspan.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/